# Integer.parseInt converts everything to zero

Tags: java, integer, parseint

Hello everyone i am new to java and i have a problem. I accept a number with the String type, then I write it to the txt variable, then I overwrite it and add "\n", and then I try to convert it to the int type, but no matter what number is, it always turns out to be zero.

```
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientConn.getInputStream()));     
        String txt = in.readLine();          
        txt = txt + "\n";                
        int number = Integer.parseInt(txt);
```

If I try to run a separate class that contains these lines of code, an error is thrown.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1
> "

and so with any number that I send.Always swears at the line `int number = Integer.parseInt(txt);`.
Tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you append a `\n` to your number?

Comment: The fact is that only when moving to the next line, I can again read the incoming data, since this piece of code is in a loop and receives numbers from the TCP client.

Comment: But what does that have to do with doing `txt = txt + "\n"`? Try getting rid of that line of code.

Comment: If `txt = txt +" \ n "` is left in the code, then after executing the line `int number = Integer.parseInt (txt);`, the value of number is passed to another class, and if I remove `txt = txt +" \ n "`, then the loop just accepts the data, but does not pass it to another class.

Comment: Your last comment makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You pass invalid input

As the comments indicate, you add a [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) to the text being parsed as an integer, thereby adulterating the input:

```
txt = txt + "\n";
```

So you are violating the contract of [`Integer.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) method. To quote the Javadoc:

> … The characters in the string must all be decimal digits…

Your attempt at parsing is throwing an `NumberFormatException` because you passed faulty input to that method.

```java
int good = Integer.parseInt( "42" ) ;
int bad = Integer.parseInt( "666" + "\n" ) ; // Throws a `NumberFormatException` because of the appended newline.
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/OdESPw).

You asked:

> Tell me how to solve this problem.

Pass valid input to the method, as documented: Text with only digits, and optional `-`/`+` in front.